# Is there a more functional way to rearrange an array into a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I'm wondering if is there a better and functional way to rearrange an array into a dictionary where each key is another array with 2 items?

I've made this two examples but I still learning functional programming and couldn't get better solution. Thank you all!

[EDIT]

@bcal has given a great solution to this; and I think that anyone is welcome to contribute with other solutions!

```
let myObjArray = ["A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]
var myIndexTwoObjArr: [Int: [String]] = [:]

// first way
var index = 0
for item in myObjArray {
    if myIndexTwoObjArr[index] == nil {
        myIndexTwoObjArr[index] = [item]
    }else if myIndexTwoObjArr[index]!.count < 2  {
        myIndexTwoObjArr[index]?.append(item)
        index += 1
    }
}

print("first way")
myIndexTwoObjArr.forEach{print($0)}

// second way
index = 0
myObjArray.forEach { item in
    if myIndexTwoObjArr[index] == nil {
        myIndexTwoObjArr[index] = [item]
    }else if myIndexTwoObjArr[index]!.count < 2  {
        myIndexTwoObjArr[index]?.append(item)
        index += 1
    }
}

print("second way")
myIndexTwoObjArr.forEach{print($0)}

// third way [thanks to bcal answer]
myIndexTwoObjArr = [:]
myIndexTwoObjArr = [Int: [String]](myObjArray.enumerated().map({($0.0/2, [$0.1])}), uniquingKeysWith: +)

print("third way [thanks to bcal answer]")
myIndexTwoObjArr.forEach{print($0)}
```

Results print:

[image: result print]

Comment: can you include the print results in your question?

Comment: @scord tkx and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` has an initializer that accepts a `Sequence` of key/value pairs, and a closure to resolve pairs with duplicate keys.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init

```
myIndexTwoObjArr = [Int: [String]](
    myObjArray.enumerated().map({($0.0/2, [$0.1])}),
    uniquingKeysWith: +
)
```

The first argument is a functional sequence...

• `enumerated` transforms the elements of your array into a sequence of `(Int, String)` tuples, where the first value in the tuple is the index of the element.

• `map` transforms the `(Int, String)` tuples into `(Int, [String])` tuples where the first value is the index ÷ 2, and the second value is an `Array` containing a single `String`.

The second argument to the `Dictionary` initializer is a closure to combine arrays with matching keys.

Comment: HI @bcal! It works perfectly, thank you very much! But I feel that I would never get into this logic.. thank you! 

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one.

```
var index: Int = 0
let myIndexTwoObjArr = Dictionary(grouping: myObjArray, by: { _ -> Int in
    index += 1
    return index
})
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Hi Sky! Thank you for your response.. but it didn't worked.. The results must be in 'pairs' of strings.. thank you anyway!